# How to check if all keys are present in list of lists element in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

Let's say there is a list of list. How can I loop through list's list 2nd element and check if all elements from other list are there?

```
list = [['foo', 2, 'bar'], ['foo', 5, 'bar'], ['foo', 9, 'bar'], ['foo', 12, 'bar']]
required = [ 2, 5, 9]


if all (item in list for item[1] in required):
    log.debug('all items exist in nested list') //<- this should be printed
```

`item[1]` is wrong in example and I can't figure out how to change it.

Comment: What is `item` here? An iterative variable or something else?

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar Yes, it's an iterative variable with purpose to loop through each element of list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = [['foo', 2, 'bar'], ['foo', 5, 'bar'], ['foo', 9, 'bar'], ['foo', 12, 'bar']]
required = [ 2, 5, 9]

chk = [any(map(lambda x: r in x, lst)) for r in required]
# [True, True, True]

if all(chk):
    print('all items exist in nested list')
```

**Test with another `required list`:**

```
lst = [['foo', 2, 'bar'], ['foo', 5, 'bar'], ['foo', 9, 'bar'], ['foo', 12, 'bar']]
required = [ 2, 5, 11]

[any(map(lambda x: r in x, lst)) for r in required]
# [True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
lst = [['foo', 2, 'bar'], ['foo', 5, 'bar'], ['foo', 9, 'bar'], ['foo', 12, 'bar']]
required = [2, 5, 9]

checker = set()

for sublist in lst:
    for elem in sublist:
        if elem in required:
            checker.add(elem)

if set(required) == checker:
    log.debug('all items exist in nested list')
```

Answer (score 0):

with sets

```
lst_set = set(x[1] for x in lst)
required=set(required)
print(lst_set&required==required)
```